# Basis of closed of ordered topology

Tags: general-topology

I have a question about ordered topologies. Suppose $X = [0,1] \times [0,1]$ is ordered by a relation $\leq$. Then a basis of open sets is given by the intervals of the form $\langle a,b \rangle = \{ x : a < x < b \}$, and sets of the form $[(0,0), a\rangle$ and $\langle b, (1,1)]$. My question is the following: is the set consisting on all intervals of the form $[a,b]$ a basis for the closed sets of the topology? I am specially interested in the case of the lexicographic order. My intuition is that it indeed is a basis of closed but I am not sure I have not missed any corner case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take set $\mathcal{C}$ of all *finite unions of* closed intervals $[a,b]$ to get a base for the closed sets: all complements of th  open base elements are of that form, e.g. $X\setminus \langle a,b\rangle = [(0,0), a] \cup [b, (1,1)]$ etc. and the complements of an open base form a closed base (and vice versa). Also, we need these finite unions, because intersections of closed intervals are going to yield order-convex sets only, and there are non-order convex closed sets too.

Comment: OK. Just to clarify the set I proposed it is a 'generating' set in the sense that every closed can be expressed as the finite union and arbitrary intersections of some of its elements but not a basis because intersection is not sufficient to generate all elements. Is that right?

Comment: @Zanzag Yes. Using intersections only is called a closed base, adding finite unions too make it a closed subbase. Not very popular notions any more (there was some theory using them in the 70's though). I was just pointing out that closed intervals are a closed subbase, not a closed base (which you called them).